# How to append a list to a specific dataframe column using for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to append a value to a dataframe by looping through the dataframe columns and comparing it to a list of columns. If the list of column is found in the dataframe then that particular column of the dataframe gets assigned a value.

Assuming this is my dataframe columns

`itching skin_rash   nodal_skin_eruptions    continuous_sneezing shivering   chills  joint_pain  stomach_pain`

And this is my list of columns

`list_columns = ['itching', 'continuous_sneezing', 'shivering']`

How do I look the list_columns up in the dataframe and assign  a value of one to each column in the dataframe that is found in the lis_column?

So for instance, the result will be like this

````
itching   skin_rash   nodal_skin_eruptions   continuous_sneezing     shivering   chills  joint_pain 
      1                                                1                 1```
````

Answer (score 0):

You want to loop over the dataframe columns. Then, in the for loop, you can check if the column name is in `list_columns`. But the thing is, in a dataframe, all columns need to have a value in every row, so you can't leave something blank like you showed in the example output. But, you can do something like putting 0s for columns where you don't want a value, and 1s for columns where you do. Here's an example.

```
for column in df.columns:
    if column in list_columns:
        new_row = {}
        for c in df.columns:
            if c in list_columns:
                new_row[c] = 1
            else:
                new_row[c] = 0

df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

I know this doesn't look pretty, and isn't super efficient, but this should work, please comment if it doesn't :)

Comment: Yes, I want to add a value to that column.

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe:

```
cols=['itching','skin_rash','nodal_skin_eruptions','continuous_sneezing','shivering','chills','joint_pain','stomach_pain']
list_columns = ['itching', 'continuous_sneezing', 'shivering']
```

Now check if it is present in columns or not then then finally assign values:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)  #created Empty dataframe
df.loc[0]=df.columns.isin(list_columns).astype(int)
```

**OR**

```
df=pd.DataFrame([df.columns.isin(list_columns).astype(int)],columns=cols)
```

output of `df`:

```
    itching     skin_rash   nodal_skin_eruptions    continuous_sneezing     shivering   chills  joint_pain  stomach_pain
0   1           0                0                          1                    1          0         0         0
```

Comment: @EmmanuelNyatefe If it solved your query then you can try considering accepting the answer so to indicate others that the issue is solved.... thnx ***:)***